# Can you use the question mark syntax when declaring a variable?

Tags: typescript

When creating a TypeScript interface one can make an entry "optional", or `type | undefined`, by adding a question mark, eg.

```
interface Foo {
    myProperty?: boolean;
}
```

Is there a way to do this when declaring a variable?  None of the following seems to work:

```
let myVar?: boolean;
let myVar: boolean?;
let myVar: boolean = undefined;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can make an entry "optional", or `type | undefined`, by adding a question mark

You can't use the `?` syntax for this with variables.

## Strict Null Checks

If you *are* using strict null checks (`strictNullChecks` compiler flag), you can explicitly allow undefined values:

```
let myVar: boolean | undefined;
```

Or nulls:

```
let myVar: boolean | null;
```

This will prevent the uninitialized variable check that the compiler performs, as shown below.

```
let myVar: boolean;

if (myVar) { // Hey coder! myVar hasn't been assigned!
  console.log('x');
}
```

If you aren't using strict null checks, the `boolean` type would already allow null and undefined with the normal type annotation.

```
let myVar: boolean;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question; you should change it to `boolean | undefined` instead of `boolean | null`, and it will behave very much like the question mark syntax for properties or function parameters.

Comment: Hi @jcalz - although that would make it more like the question, it would mean a programmer assigning `undefined` to a variable (as block scoped variables in this case cannot be used before they are initialized as the compiler catches that common mistake). When a programmer wants to assign "no value", the correct way to do that is to assign `null`.

Comment: And OP asked how to do declare `myVar` as a possibly-unset `boolean` value, not how to set it to "no value".  TypeScript (check the playground) does not complain about an uninitialized variable if it is declared as `let myVar: boolean | undefined` and then used later (as long as it's checked).  If you disagree maybe I should make my own answer since we have different perspectives.

Comment: @jcalz - you are correct that this would allow the example that is disallowed above.

Comment: Kinda sucks that you can use the question mark syntax in interfaces but not variable declarations especially considering C# lets you say `int? foo = null;` but OK.