# Typescript - Whats the best way to declare variable but assign later?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a slight problem with Typescript and not sure what the best way to go around this and I don't want to be adding extra logic for the sake of the typescript compiler, so here is the issue, this is for a React app:

```
let myVar: ComplexType;
let response;

useEffect(() => doApiCall());

if (loading) { 
  return <Spinner /> 
}

// from API
if (response) {
  myVar = response.value;
}

return (<MyComp data={myVar} />)
```

So the problem is that I can declare a variable with a type and assign it later, the compiler complains that I am using it before assignment.

I can't assign null either because the types do no match.

I tried to change the type to 'ComplexType | null' however that complains that my component does not take a prop with that type because of the null. I can't go ahead and change the type of my props either because that leads to more issues.

So I am a bit stumped on what the best approach is.

I found that if wrapped my component return in an if logic 'if (myVar)' then it works but I feel like I am adding extra logic to satisfy the compiler.

How do you all handle this?

I tried to create a dummy example that showcases my problem below:

```
interface MyType {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

let item: MyType;
let loading = true;

setTimeout(() => {
  loading = true;
  item = { a: 'test', b: 7 };
})

if (!loading) {
  doSomething(item);
}

function doSomething(x: MyType) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set `response` and `myVar` with a `useState` since I assume they'll be changed after request completes?

Comment: Does the code here count as a [mcve]?  I'd love to be able to just drop that into something like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), reproduce your issue, and advise you.  But it doesn't compile at all, really, so we'd have to guess what will fix your issue.

Comment: A good practice is to set data mockup for your unit tests. Every data / variable must be challenged, tested, and can even be tweaked in the future. By using a mockup you define a data structure you can rely on. 
So I would say create Class, with dummy variable inside, I can show you how in angular, not sure it's the same in react.

Comment: Possibly related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875575/can-you-use-the-question-mark-syntax-when-declaring-a-variable

Comment: Ok I have added some dummy code to try and showcase the problem, as a summary the problem is if you define a variable with a type, you have to assign it immediately otherwise there are various problems which I pointed out above. This is quite common for values that need to be computed after an API response.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful as I am just learning, but I think there is syntax for declaring a variable and defining it later:

```
var!: variableType;
```